# View is shown instantly even though I use handler.postDelayed

Tags: android

I have a two RelativeLayout where I have set their visibility to gone using,

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

And then on the root element of the activity which is also a RelativeLayout, I have added this attribute

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Here's my activity java code

```
RelativeLayout rellay1, rellay2;
Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    rellay1 = findViewById(R.id.rellay1);
    rellay2 = findViewById(R.id.rellay2);

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            rellay1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rellay2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 2000);

}
```

When I run the app, the views get displayed immediately without any wait. If I increase the time to 5s, still same results.

I've looked at the logs when starting the activity and nothing suspicious.

**NOTE**

When answering questions on SO, I sometimes find it hard to understand the users problem when it's cluttered with XML, so I tried hard to keep my question clean. But that might not be enough to diagnose what's wrong with my code so I'm adding a minimal version of the xml for the parent and two child RelativeLayouts without their contents, just the attributes. If more detail is needed I'd be happy to provide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/grad_bg"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_view_logo"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rellay1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_view_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rellay2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

From the XML above, you'll see that my intention is to have only the ImageView visible initially and the rest should become visible after 2s.

I have looked similar questions about Handler@postDelayed but the problems are not exactly like mine so the solutions where not applicable.

**UPDATE**

The only problem here seems to be my lack of proper understanding of the android lifecycle(I'm a beginner here). I carried out an experiment by killing all running apps and tried launching my app again and I saw the animation.

So I guess what was happening here was that, the view had already been created and since my activity was still alive even though I had exited the app, subsequent launches of the App loaded a previously saved instance of the activity and that is why it seemed as if the animation wasn't working.

Comment: They show immediately as in they're already there, or they show immediately as in, when the Runnable executes, they don't animate?

Comment: Well they don't animate. The behavior I was expecting was, I launch the App, I see just the logo then 2s later, I see the rest of the views. But that doesn't happen. When I launch the app all the views are already there

Comment: How do you know that the view is visible when the size of them are all 0dp (because they wrap empty content)?

Comment: See the update. There wasn't an application error, just user error. Now I'm not sure what the policy says. I mean should the question be deleted?

Comment: As far as I understand it, you may either delete the question or you leave it here (that's what I'd suggest) and you could write an answer to your question describing the real reason for the seeming "misbehavior". There is a lesson to be learned here, and future readers may be happy to find a hint on what they are missing. Answering your own question may seem strange but it's OK, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)